# How Android phones get connected WIFI passwords through ADB

Tags: android, adb, android-wifi

I have a rooted android 13 phone, and I hope to get connected WIFI passwords with adb.
I have tried

`adb shell cat /data/misc/wifi/*.conf`

It does not work.  It seems not for android 13.
So i want to know what the cmd for android 13.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Please click on Pair Device it is toward to app, and scan qR code from UR android device "Developer options->Wireless debugging" on it after switch on it will show the pair device with the QR code scan it.
it will be connected to the device.

Comment: Sorry , its a machine without the origin android setting.

Answer (score 0):

Found the wifi password store file for android 13

```
private static final String STORE_FILE_NAME = "WifiConfigStore.xml";

private static final String STORE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "wifi";
```

So the adb cmd for android 13 is:

```
adb shell cat /data/misc/wifi/*.xml
```